# how to use another website to make a query with php?

Tags: php, html

I want to use  [sci-hub.cc](http://sci-hub.cc) to download scientific papers, but it is in russian and it is not easy to use. 
It has a textfield for enter DOI or paper link.

Now, I want to make a website that, when users insert paper link, send this link to sci-hub as a query and then download it. How can I do this in php?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't do it, my friend. The copyright laws are just insane nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how your page is working but what you looking for is a "POST" Request with.
The code below "does" the same if you type in something in the field on your page:

```
            <php
    $url = 'http://sci-hub.cc/';
    $data = ['Request'=>'TEXT FOR FIELD'];
    $options = array('http' => array(
                     'method'  => 'POST',
                     'content' => http_build_query($data),
                     'header'=>  "Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n")
   );
       $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
       $result   = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much. i'm testing your code and telling the resaults.